# use Excel VBA Hyperlink form to add link to userform

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, userform

so I've figured out that this line of code:

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show

will bring up the add hyperlink form. However, this form exclusively outputs the link to the selected cell. I was wondering if there was a way to put the output in a userform input box? If not, is there a way I can view the default InsertHyperlink form and edit it so I can? Thank you for your response!

Comment: re: *put the output in a userform input box?*   What do you mean by that? and re : *.. and edit it so I can?* its feel like this sentence not complete..i mean *so I can* what?

Comment: You could select an empty cell, allow the dialog to complete, then pull the hyperlink out from the cell if one was added.

Comment: Of course! Thank you Tim.